# Redirect 301 Transfer to New Domain Output URL is Ugly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, query-string, http-status-code-301, mod-alias

I am moving my blog to a new domain. I am trying to do this through .htaccess. While the redirect is okay - the output URL is 'ugly'

example in old domain .htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 /archives/2009/06/02/hello-world/ http://indiapoint.net/archives/2009/06/02/hello-world/
```

So if we click

```
http://www.i3pep.org/archives/2009/06/02/hello-world/
```

the redirect is to

```
http://indiapoint.net/archives/2009/06/02/hello-world/?year=2009&monthnum=06&day=02&name=hello-world&page=
```

Please suggest what should be done

thanks
Anup

Comment: Show the rest of the origin htaccess as well as the destination htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This is not helping with your .htaccess file question above but if you are just looking to get 301 redirects from one domain to another but the url stays exactly the same then I would recommend checking with your domain registrar to see if they provide this feature.

For instance, GoDaddy lets you forward a domain using a 301 redirect and it will keep the full url.  So in your example above you would go to the i3pep.org domain and tell your domain registrar to forward it (at least in GoDaddy you can do this) to indiapoint.net (make sure you specify 301 redirect).

Then a request to:
http://www.i3pep.org/archives/2009/06/02/hello-world/

Will get automatically 301 redirected to:
http://www.indiapoint.net/archives/2009/06/02/hello-world/

This has worked for me on multiple domains that I have hosted with GoDaddy.

-Jeff